# Need help to understand logic in behind this function

Tags: python-3.x

My question is in two parts:

(1): How can I understand the following part of the defined function:

```
for passenger_index, passenger in titanic_df.iterrows():
passenger_id=passenger[“PassengerId”]
```

The complete function is:

```
def complex_heuristic(titanic_df):
    predictions={}
    for passenger_index, passenger in titanic_df.iterrows():
        passenger_id=passenger["PassengerId"]

    if (passenger["Sex"]=="female"):
            predictions[passenger_id]=1
    elif(passenger["Pclass"]==1 and passenger["Age"]<18):
            predictions[passenger_id]=1
    else:
            predictions[passenger_id]=0

            return predictions
```

What's the “passenger_index” here stands for and how these two lines work?

(2)I am running this code to predict `survival(1)` or `perish(0)` for all the datapoint but I am getting the same just the very first entry. Where have I gone wrong in writing this code.

I expected the output for all 891 entries as below:

```
> {1: 0,  2: 1,  3: 1,  4: 1,  5: 0,  6: 0,  7: 0,  8: 0,  9: 1,  10: 1,
> 11: 1,  12: 1,  13: 0,  14: 0,  15: 1,  16: 1,  17: 0,  18: 0,  19: 1,
> 20: 1,  21: 0,  22: 0,  23: 1,  24: 0,  25: 1,  26: 1,  27: 0,  28: 0,
> 29: 1,  30: 0,  31: 0,  32: 1,  33: 1,  34: 0,  35: 0,  36: 0,  37: 0,
> 38: 0,  39: 1,  40: 1,  41: 1,  42: 1,  43: 0,  44: 1,  45: 1,  46: 0,
> 47: 0,  48: 1,  49: 0,  50: 1,  51: 0,  52: 0,  53: 1,  54: 1,  55: 0,
> 56: 0,  57: 1,  58: 0,  59: 1,  60: 0,  61: 0,  62: 1,  63: 0,  64: 0,
> 65: 0,  66: 0,  67: 1,  68: 0,  69: 1,  70: 0,  71: 0,  72: 1,  73: 0,
> 74: 0,  75: 0,  76: 0,  77: 0,  78: 0,  79: 0,  80: 1,  81: 0,  82: 0,
> 83: 1,  84: 0,  85: 1,  86: 1,  87: 0,  88: 0,  89: 1,  90: 0,  91: 0,
> 92: 0,  93: 0,  94: 0,  95: 0,  96: 0,  97: 0,  98: 0,  99: 1,  100:
> 0,  101: 1,  102: 0,  103: 0,  104: 0,  105: 0,  106: 0,  107: 1, 
> 108: 0,  109: 0,  110: 1,  111: 0,  112: 1,  113: 0,  114: 1,  115: 1,
> 116: 0,  117: 0,  118: 0,  119: 0,  120: 1,  121: 0,  122: 0,  123: 0,
> 124: 1,  125: 0,  126: 0,  127: 0,  128: 0,  129: 1,  130: 0,  131: 0,
> 132: 0,  133: 1,  134: 1,  135: 0,  136: 0,  137: 1,  138: 0,  139: 0,
> 140: 0,  141: 1,  142: 1,  143: 1,  144: 0,  145: 0,  146: 0,  147: 0,
> 148: 1,  149: 0,  150: 0,  151: 0,  152: 1,  153: 0,  154: 0,  155: 0,
> 156: 0,  157: 1,  158: 0,  159: 0,  160: 0,  161: 0,  162: 1,  163: 0,
> 164: 0,  165: 0,  166: 0,  167: 1,  168: 1,  169: 0,  170: 0,  171: 0,
> 172: 0,  173: 1,  174: 0,  175: 0,  176: 0,  177: 0,  178: 1,  179: 0,
> 180: 0,  181: 1,  182: 0,  183: 0,  184: 0,  185: 1,  186: 0,  187: 1,
> 188: 0,  189: 0,  190: 0,  191: 1,  192: 0,  193: 1,  194: 0,  195: 1,
> 196: 1,  197: 0,  198: 0,  199: 1,  200: 1,  201: 0,  202: 0,  203: 0,
> 204: 0,  205: 0,  206: 1,  207: 0,  208: 0,  209: 1,  210: 0,  211: 0,
> 212: 1,  213: 0,  214: 0,  215: 0,  216: 1,  217: 1,  218: 0,  219: 1,
> 220: 0,  221: 0,  222: 0,  223: 0,  224: 0,  225: 0,  226: 0,  227: 0,
> 228: 0,  229: 0,  230: 1,  231: 1,  232: 0,  233: 0,  234: 1,  235: 0,
> 236: 1,  237: 0,  238: 1,  239: 0,  240: 0,  241: 1,  242: 1,  243: 0,
> 244: 0,  245: 0,  246: 0,  247: 1,  248: 1,  249: 0,  250: 0,  251: 0,
> 252: 1,  253: 0,  254: 0,  255: 1,  256: 1,  257: 1,  258: 1,  259: 1,
> 260: 1,  261: 0,  262: 0,  263: 0,  264: 0,  265: 1,  266: 0,  267: 0,
> 268: 0,  269: 1,  270: 1,  271: 0,  272: 0,  273: 1,  274: 0,  275: 1,
> 276: 1,  277: 1,  278: 0,  279: 0,  280: 1,  281: 0,  282: 0,  283: 0,
> 284: 0,  285: 0,  286: 0,  287: 0,  288: 0,  289: 0,  290: 1,  291: 1,
> 292: 1,  293: 0,  294: 1,  295: 0,  296: 0,  297: 0,  298: 1,  299: 0,
> 300: 1,  301: 1,  302: 0,  303: 0,  304: 1,  305: 0,  306: 0,  307: 1,
> 308: 1,  309: 0,  310: 1,  311: 1,  312: 1,  313: 1,  314: 0,  315: 0,
> 316: 1,  317: 1,  318: 0,  319: 1,  320: 1,  321: 0,  322: 0,  323: 1,
> 324: 1,  325: 0,  326: 1,  327: 0,  328: 1,  329: 1,  330: 1,  331: 1,
> 332: 0,  333: 0,  334: 0,  335: 1,  336: 0,  337: 0,  338: 1,  339: 0,
> 340: 0,  341: 0,  342: 1,  343: 0,  344: 0,  345: 0,  346: 1,  347: 1,
> 348: 1,  349: 0,  350: 0,  351: 0,  352: 0,  353: 0,  354: 0,  355: 0,
> 356: 0,  357: 1,  358: 1,  359: 1,  360: 1,  361: 0,  362: 0,  363: 1,
> 364: 0,  365: 0,  366: 0,  367: 1,  368: 1,  369: 1,  370: 1,  371: 0,
> 372: 0,  373: 0,  374: 0,  375: 1,  376: 1,  377: 1,  378: 0,  379: 0,
> 380: 0,  381: 1,  382: 1,  383: 0,  384: 1,  385: 0,  386: 0,  387: 0,
> 388: 1,  389: 0,  390: 1,  391: 0,  392: 0,  393: 0,  394: 1,  395: 1,
> 396: 0,  397: 1,  398: 0,  399: 0,  400: 1,  401: 0,  402: 0,  403: 1,
> 404: 0,  405: 1,  406: 0,  407: 0,  408: 0,  409: 0,  410: 1,  411: 0,
> 412: 0,  413: 1,  414: 0,  415: 0,  416: 1,  417: 1,  418: 1,  419: 0,
> 420: 1,  421: 0,  422: 0,  423: 0,  424: 1,  425: 0,  426: 0,  427: 1,
> 428: 1,  429: 0,  430: 0,  431: 0,  432: 1,  433: 1,  434: 0,  435: 0,
> 436: 1,  437: 1,  438: 1,  439: 0,  440: 0,  441: 1,  442: 0,  443: 0,
> 444: 1,  445: 0,  446: 0,  447: 1,  448: 0,  449: 1,  450: 0,  451: 0,
> 452: 0,  453: 0,  454: 0,  455: 0,  456: 0,  457: 0,  458: 1,  459: 1,
> 460: 0,  461: 0,  462: 0,  463: 0,  464: 0,  465: 0,  466: 0,  467: 0,
> 468: 0,  469: 0,  470: 1,  471: 0,  472: 0,  473: 1,  474: 1,  475: 1,
> 476: 0,  477: 0,  478: 0,  479: 0,  480: 1,  481: 0,  482: 0,  483: 0,
> 484: 1,  485: 0,  486: 1,  487: 1,  488: 0,  489: 0,  490: 0,  491: 0,
> 492: 0,  493: 0,  494: 0,  495: 0,  496: 0,  497: 1,  498: 0,  499: 1,
> 500: 0,  501: 0,  502: 1,  503: 1,  504: 1,  505: 1,  506: 0,  507: 1,
> 508: 0,  509: 0,  510: 0,  511: 0,  512: 0,  513: 0,  514: 1,  515: 0,
> 516: 0,  517: 1,  518: 0,  519: 1,  520: 0,  521: 1,  522: 0,  523: 0,
> 524: 1,  525: 0,  526: 0,  527: 1,  528: 0,  529: 0,  530: 0,  531: 1,
> 532: 0,  533: 0,  534: 1,  535: 1,  536: 1,  537: 0,  538: 1,  539: 0,
> 540: 1,  541: 1,  542: 1,  543: 1,  544: 0,  545: 0,  546: 0,  547: 1,
> 548: 0,  549: 0,  550: 0,  551: 0,  552: 0,  553: 0,  554: 0,  555: 1,
> 556: 0,  557: 1,  558: 0,  559: 1,  560: 1,  561: 0,  562: 0,  563: 0,
> 564: 0,  565: 1,  566: 0,  567: 0,  568: 1,  569: 0,  570: 0,  571: 0,
> 572: 1,  573: 0,  574: 1,  575: 0,  576: 0,  577: 1,  578: 1,  579: 1,
> 580: 0,  581: 1,  582: 1,  583: 0,  584: 0,  585: 0,  586: 1,  587: 0,
> 588: 0,  589: 0,  590: 0,  591: 0,  592: 1,  593: 0,  594: 1,  595: 0,
> 596: 0,  597: 1,  598: 0,  599: 0,  600: 0,  601: 1,  602: 0,  603: 0,
> 604: 0,  605: 0,  606: 0,  607: 0,  608: 0,  609: 1,  610: 1,  611: 1,
> 612: 0,  613: 1,  614: 0,  615: 0,  616: 1,  617: 0,  618: 1,  619: 1,
> 620: 0,  621: 0,  622: 0,  623: 0,  624: 0,  625: 0,  626: 0,  627: 0,
> 628: 1,  629: 0,  630: 0,  631: 0,  632: 0,  633: 0,  634: 0,  635: 1,
> 636: 1,  637: 0,  638: 0,  639: 1,  640: 0,  641: 0,  642: 1,  643: 1,
> 644: 0,  645: 1,  646: 0,  647: 0,  648: 0,  649: 0,  650: 1,  651: 0,
> 652: 1,  653: 0,  654: 1,  655: 1,  656: 0,  657: 0,  658: 1,  659: 0,
> 660: 0,  661: 0,  662: 0,  663: 0,  664: 0,  665: 0,  666: 0,  667: 0,
> 668: 0,  669: 0,  670: 1,  671: 1,  672: 0,  673: 0,  674: 0,  675: 0,
> 676: 0,  677: 0,  678: 1,  679: 1,  680: 0,  681: 1,  682: 0,  683: 0,
> 684: 0,  685: 0,  686: 0,  687: 0,  688: 0,  689: 0,  690: 1,  691: 0,
> 692: 1,  693: 0,  694: 0,  695: 0,  696: 0,  697: 0,  698: 1,  699: 0,
> 700: 0,  701: 1,  702: 0,  703: 1,  704: 0,  705: 0,  706: 0,  707: 1,
> 708: 0,  709: 1,  710: 0,  711: 1,  712: 0,  713: 0,  714: 0,  715: 0,
> 716: 0,  717: 1,  718: 1,  719: 0,  720: 0,  721: 1,  722: 0,  723: 0,
> 724: 0,  725: 0,  726: 0,  727: 1,  728: 1,  729: 0,  730: 1,  731: 1,
> 732: 0,  733: 0,  734: 0,  735: 0,  736: 0,  737: 1,  738: 0,  739: 0,
> 740: 0,  741: 0,  742: 0,  743: 1,  744: 0,  745: 0,  746: 0,  747: 0,
> 748: 1,  749: 0,  750: 0,  751: 1,  752: 0,  753: 0,  754: 0,  755: 1,
> 756: 0,  757: 0,  758: 0,  759: 0,  760: 1,  761: 0,  762: 0,  763: 0,
> 764: 1,  765: 0,  766: 1,  767: 0,  768: 1,  769: 0,  770: 0,  771: 0,
> 772: 0,  773: 1,  774: 0,  775: 1,  776: 0,  777: 0,  778: 1,  779: 0,
> 780: 1,  781: 1,  782: 1,  783: 0,  784: 0,  785: 0,  786: 0,  787: 1,
> 788: 0,  789: 0,  790: 0,  791: 0,  792: 0,  793: 1,  794: 0,  795: 0,
> 796: 0,  797: 1,  798: 1,  799: 0,  800: 1,  801: 0,  802: 1,  803: 0,
> 804: 0,  805: 0,  806: 0,  807: 0,  808: 1,  809: 0,  810: 1,  811: 0,
> 812: 0,  813: 0,  814: 1,  815: 0,  816: 0,  817: 1,  818: 0,  819: 0,
> 820: 0,  821: 1,  822: 0,  823: 0,  824: 1,  825: 0,  826: 0,  827: 0,
> 828: 0,  829: 0,  830: 1,  831: 1,  832: 0,  833: 0,  834: 0,  835: 0,
> 836: 1,  837: 0,  838: 0,  839: 0,  840: 0,  841: 0,  842: 0,  843: 1,
> 844: 0,  845: 0,  846: 0,  847: 0,  848: 0,  849: 0,  850: 1,  851: 0,
> 852: 0,  853: 1,  854: 1,  855: 1,  856: 1,  857: 1,  858: 0,  859: 1,
> 860: 0,  861: 0,  862: 0,  863: 1,  864: 1,  865: 0,  866: 1,  867: 1,
> 868: 0,  869: 0,  870: 0,  871: 0,  872: 1,  873: 0,  874: 0,  875: 1,
> 876: 1,  877: 0,  878: 0,  879: 0,  880: 1,  881: 1,  882: 0,  883: 1,
> 884: 0,  885: 0,  886: 1,  887: 0,  888: 1,  889: 1,  890: 0,  891: 0}
```

but I am getting the output for just the last entry as

```
> {891:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)   Following line of code indicates that `for` loop will iterate over each row of dataframe and `passenger_index` will store the index of the row while `passenger` will store the content of the row.
second line takes the `"Passenger_Id"` of the current row and stores in variable `passenger_id`

```
for passenger_index, passenger in titanic_df.iterrows():
    passenger_id=passenger["PassengerId"]
```

2) Code indentation is not correct in your code. Please write it as follow.

```
def complex_heuristic(titanic_df):
    predictions={}
    for passenger_index, passenger in titanic_df.iterrows():
        passenger_id=passenger["PassengerId"]

        if (passenger["Sex"]=="female"):
            predictions[passenger_id] = 1
        elif(passenger["Pclass"]==1 and passenger["Age"]<18):
            predictions[passenger_id] = 1
        else:
            predictions[passenger_id] = 0
    return predictions
```